# Is $(e^\pi-\pi^e)$ positive or negative? why?

Tags: calculus

Is  $(e^\pi-\pi^e)$  positive or negative? why?

Answer (score 1):

If $a>b\geq e$, then $a^b<b^a$. It follows from the fact that the function
$$ f(x)=\frac{\log x}{x} $$
is decreasing over $I=(e,+\infty)$, since:
$$ f'(x) = \frac{1-\log x}{x^2} $$
is negative over $I$.

Comment: thanks. was helpful for me

Comment: Shouldn't it be $a > b \geq e$ in order to apply this to the actual question?

Comment: @rubik: yes, you're right. Now fixed.