# Show that: $e^{\pi}-\pi^{e} >\frac12$ without calculator

Tags: exponentiation, irrational-numbers, pi, conjectures, transcendental-numbers

> **Show that:**
> $$e^{\pi}-\pi^{e} >\frac12$$

I am not sure, if anything can be done using elementary methods.  Because $e$ and $\pi$ are not algebraic numbers.  Therefore, I find it impossible to prove this with elementary techniques.  Maybe using the elementary formula $\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n\rightarrow e$ for $e$ would work.  But there is no such formula for $\pi$.  I guess there is no other way than using series, right?

Comment: The value is $0.681535...$ (so it isn't a "conjecture").  And why did you choose (arbitrarily?) $1/2$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I didn't choose. I saw this problem in telegram.

Comment: The statement is obviously true.

Comment: Any connection with [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) ?

Comment: @User: Since there's no actual conjecture involved, perhaps you should restate your question as something like "Is it possible to show $e^\pi-\pi^e>\frac12$ by elementary methods?"

Comment: @Blue Thank you very much.

Comment: @Blue Can this question be a dupe? I could not find  a duplicat

Comment: @User: An [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24e%5E%7B%5Cpi%7D-%5Cpi%5Ee%24&p=1) search shows a few questions that are at least related. ["Proving that $e^\pi−\pi^e<1$ without using a calculator"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1410230/409), ["Is $(e^\pi-\pi^e)$ positive or negative? why?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1138188/409) (which was closed as a duplicate of ["Comparing $e^\pi$ and $\pi^e$ without calculating them"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7892/409), and others you can check. You (and/or the community) can decide if your question is a duplicate.

Comment: I wonder whether there's some bound can be obtained for $e^x-x^e$, and then use that $\pi-e$ is greater than something (like $2/5$ or some similar). I was hoping we could use $1/e$, but that just barely doesn't work.

Comment: @User... Gee... OK, then, why did the *original question posers* choose (arbitrarily) $1/2$?  Rather:  What's so special about $1/2$?

Answer (score 4):

This solution isn’t elegant, but the fact that $\pi$ and $e$ aren’t algebraic doesn’t mean we can’t bound this expression easily. You can use finite decimal approximations. Since $\pi$ and $e$ are computable, we can compute their decimal expansions $\pi = 3.14159 \cdots$ and $e = 2.71828 \cdots$

Using these expansions, we can bound: $3.141 < \pi < 3.142$ and $2.718 < e < 2.719$

If we have that $a < b < c$ and $x < y < z$, we may bound $a^x < b^y < c^z$. Thus we may bound:

$$ \begin{align*} & e^{\pi} > 2.718^{3.141} > 23.11 \\ & \pi^e < 3.142^{2.719} < 22.49 \end{align*}$$

Since these are rational numbers, there are no issues in bounding these expressions. Simply compute the first few digits by hand.

Then it follows that $e^\pi - \pi^e > 23.11 - 22.49 = .62 > .5$

Comment: "Simply compute the first few digits by hand" How...? Is there a way to generally compute $a^b$ when $b$ is a non-integral rational?

Comment: Yeah of course. I mean it’s not fun, but it’s possible. Separate $a^{n/m} = a^n a^{1/m}$. $a^n$ is trivial, and $a^{1/m}$ can be approximated digit-by-digit with a simple algorithm by hand. Like I said, this solution isn’t elegant at all.